# Invariant Violation on React HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Missing something obvious here. I'm getting `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid` for the following HOC:

```
export const ButtonWithComponent = (Comp) => props =>
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={props.onPress}
  style={{
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }}
  hitSlop={{ left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5 }}
>
  <Comp />
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

used as follows:

```
const PencilButton = ButtonWithComponent(
    <Icon name="pencil" color={APP_MAIN_COLOR} size={30} type="entypo" />
);

class myClass extends Component {

...

render() {
    return (
        <PencilButton onPress={() => console.log('')} />
    );
}

}
```

I've logged `console.log(PencilButton)` and see the expected stateless component function taking props as an argument. My import is as follows:

```
import { ButtonWithComponent } from '../path/to/ButtonWithComponent.js'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important in React to differentiate Components and Elements:

```
const MyComponent = () => <span /> // Component
const myElement = <MyComponent /> // Element
```

So your HOC accepts Component, but you pass the element to it: `ButtonWithComponent(<Icon/>)`

You have two options:

1. Pass Component to ButtonWithComponent
2. Refactor ButtonWithComponent to accept Elements:

   ```
   export const ButtonWithComponent = (children) => props =>
   <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={props.onPress}
     style={{
       paddingHorizontal: 10,
       flexDirection: 'row',
       justifyContent: 'flex-end',
       alignItems: 'center'
     }}
     hitSlop={{ left: 5, right: 5, top: 5, bottom: 5 }}
   >
      {children}
   </TouchableOpacity>;
   ```

Comment: thanks, your answer makes sense. with 2, is the only advantage of this readability? After all I could just use:
`<ButtonWithComponent>`
    `<Child />`
`</ButtonWithComponent>`

and use `{props.children}` in ButtonComponent

Comment: Usually HOC accepts Component. So, yes, for 2nd case it's better to pass nodes simply as childrens.

Comment: Also as alternative to HOCs you can use render props https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: Yes, [I read about them](https://lucasmreis.github.io/blog/simple-react-patterns/) and how contentious they are... I'll wait for a little more consensus before using them :)

Comment: ^ this was dumb - I use render props all.the.time. now